Footnote in tables in revtex4-2 gets wrapped when multirow is used
MWE:
\documentclass[twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prb]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Using star * in \texttt{\textbackslash multirow}}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \multirow{2}{*}{Layer before ligand attachment\footnote{+CH3 means one methyl group is already attached}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-CH3}\\
        \cmidrule{2-3}
         & RAE & eRAE \\
        \midrule
        1 Nb +CH3 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Using 3cm in \texttt{\textbackslash multirow}}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \multirow{2}{3cm}{Layer before ligand attachment\footnote{+CH3 means one methyl group is already attached}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-CH3}\\
        \cmidrule{2-3}
         & RAE & eRAE \\
        \midrule
        1 Nb +CH3 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

This renders

I want the text "Layer before..." in the cell to be wrapped while the footnote is not wrapped.

You don't need \multirow: nest a smashed tabular instead.
\documentclass[twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prb]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\caption{A caption to the table}

\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} Layer before ligand \\ attachment%
  \footnote{+CH3 means one methyl group is already attached} \end{tabular}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{-CH3}\\
\cmidrule{2-3}
& RAE & eRAE \\
\midrule
1 Nb +CH3 & 0 & 0
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}


If you want to state a target width, you can use the \footnotemark and \footnotetext mechanism, but with a twist due to the double processing made with ruledtabular (which I find graphically horrible, but it's a different story).
\documentclass[twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prb]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newcommand{\rultabfnmark}{\footnotemark\addtocounter{mpfootnote}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\caption{A caption to the table}

\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\smash{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright
  Layer before ligand attachment\rultabfnmark}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{-CH3}\\
\cmidrule{2-3}
& RAE & eRAE \\
\midrule
1 Nb +CH3 & 0 & 0
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{+CH3 means one methyl group is already attached}
\end{ruledtabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}

The output is the same as before (in the particular case, of course).

Thanks! This is clever and is enough for this specific project. But what if I have a long text and I want to have it wrapped automatically to fit in a given width, like 3cm?

@BoyoungZheng I added a version for it.
